# C# - Grouping on multiple columns and summation of other columns in list

Tags: c#, list, linq, aggregate, grouping

I have a list which contains duplicate data for few properties and based on those properties, I want to group data and summation of other properties data.

List Example -

```
     Prop1     Prop2     Prop3     Bal1     Bal2 
    -----------------------------------------------
     X         Y         Z         50       50   
     A         B         C         100      200
     A         B         C         100      200
```

I want to group on Prop1, Prop2 and Prop3 properties and summation of Bal1 and Bal2. I need final result of this list is as below:

```
 Prop1     Prop2     Prop3     Bal1     Bal2 
-----------------------------------------------
 X         Y         Z         50       50   
 A         B         C         200      400
```

How can I modify the same list and achieve this with best practice?